# c++ overload 3 function with different parameters(int,*int,&int)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading, sqrt

So i have this homework to do "Using functions overloading define 3 functions with the same name but with different prams type (int, int*, int&) that will return the square root of the value." Well i made it but i don't know it gives me this error:"ambiguous call to overloaded function". I try to fix it but no succes...
Here's my code it's quite simple:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double rad(int);
double rad(int*);
double rad(int&);

int main(){
int a,*pt=&a;
cin>>a;
cout<<"Radical din "<<a<<" este "<<rad(a)<<endl;
cout<<"Radical din "<<a<<" este "<<rad(pt)<<endl;
cout<<"Radical din "<<a<<" este "<<rad(&a)<<endl;
return 0;
}

double rad(int x){
    return  (sqrt(x));
}
double rad(int *x){
    return  (sqrt(*x));
}
double rad(int &x){
    return  (sqrt(x));
}
```

Comment: `double rad(int &x)` and `double rad(int x)` confuses the compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given these declarations:

```
double rad(int);   // (1)
double rad(int*);  // (2)
double rad(int&);  // (3)
```

Dealing with `(2)` is easy. We either have a pointer, or we don't, there's no possible confusion. The question then is, what happens with:

```
int a;
rad(a);
```

Well, here both `(1)` and `(3)` work. And there's actually no preference between the two anywhere in the rules for determining what the best viable candidate is! It's an **ambiguous** call, so this will always fail to compile.

---

Note that it *is* possible to explicitly call `(1)` though - by simply passing in an `int` that you can't take a reference to:

```
rad(4); // calls (1), since neither (2) nor (3) are possible
```

Note also that it is possible to call `(1)` or `(3)` even with a named variable like `a`, but we can't rely upon overload resolution to do it. We have to explicitly tell the compiler which function we want. And to do that, we have to cast the name:

```
int a;
static_cast<double(*)(int)>(rad)(a);  // calls (1) explicitly
static_cast<double(*)(int&)>(rad)(a); // calls (3) explicitly
```

Comment: To call the reference argument function one can disambiguate the call by `static_cast`-ing the function name to pointer to this function type. I wouldn't call the assignment "illogical". Rather, it teaches the good student (who tries to call the function overloads) something about overload resolution ambiguity, and about what to not do.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah that's a very good point. Removed that line.

Answer (score 1):

```
int test_val = 5;    

// accept rvalue reference
double rad(int &&x) {
    return  (sqrt(x));
}
rad(5);

// accept pointer
double rad(int *x) {
    return  (sqrt(*x));
}
rad(&test_val);

// accept lvalue reference
double rad(int &x) {
    return  (sqrt(x));
}
rad(test_val);
```

Comment: Perhaps you should provide an explanation along with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use rvalue references ('int&&') instead of lvalue references ('int&') in third case to not confuse compiler. Like this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

double rad(int);
double rad(int*);
double rad(int&&);

int main(){
int a,*pt=&a;
cin>>a;
cout<<"Radical din "<<a<<" este "<<rad(a)<<endl;
cout<<"Radical din "<<a<<" este "<<rad(pt)<<endl;
cout<<"Radical din "<<a<<" este "<<rad(&a)<<endl;
return 0;
}

double rad(int x){
    return  (sqrt(x));
}
double rad(int *x){
    return  (sqrt(*x));
}
double rad(int &&x){
    return  (sqrt(x));
}
```

Comment: You should use rvalue references because 'int' can be implicitly casted to 'int&'.

Comment: Well, i run the code with debugger and it seems like the third function is never called. For rad(pt) and rad(&a) they use the same function double rad(int *x);

Answer (score 0):

A prelude to the other answers:
calls to

```
rad(int)
```

and

```
rad(int& x)
```

look the same - rad(a).
The line

```
rad(&a);
```

calls rad(int*);